# What is the lie algebra of ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$?

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

The ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ group is used in physics. From the references[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028459/how-to-show-spincv-is-isomorphic-to-spinv-times-z-2-s1) I found that

$$
{\rm Spin}^c={\rm Spin}(V) \times S^1
$$

But I was not able to find any references for its lie algebra. Specifically, I am interested in the ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ case. What is its lie algebra?

Furthermore, this page[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure#cite_note-12) mentions that ${\rm Spin}^c(n)$ is used in physics, but does not confirm that it is ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$ specifically that is used in physics. I suspect that it is, but it would be nice to confirm that, also.

---

My attempt:

I know that $S^1$ is isomorphic to $U(1)$. So would $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) \oplus i$ be an isomorphic representation of ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$?

Comment: ${\rm Spin}^c(V)$ is ${\rm Spin}(V)\times_{\Bbb Z_2}S^1$, to be precise. This is double covered by ${\rm Spin}(V)\times S^1$, so they have the same lie algebra. The lie algebra of a direct product is a direct sum of the corresponding lie algebras, so as a real lie algebra, ${\frak spin}^c(V)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm spin}(V)\oplus{\frak u}(1)$, yes.

Comment: @runway44 What is the difference between spin(V) and spin(n)?

Comment: ${\rm Spin}(V)$ is defined for a space $V$ assumed to have a quadratic form / nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form, and ${\rm Spin}(n)$ is a particular case where $V=\Bbb R^n$ with the usual dot product. More generally, ${\rm Spin}(p,q)$ is the case where $V=\Bbb R^{p,q}$ is pseudo-Euclidean, which is $\Bbb R^{p+q}$ equipped with $$\langle x,y\rangle=(x_1y_1+\cdots+x_py_p)-(x_{p+1}y_{p+1}+\cdots+x_{p+q}y_{p+q})$$ (or the opposite sign convention). But with the notation ${\rm Spin}(V)$, there is no assumption of $V$ having a choice of coordinates.

Comment: Note also ${\rm Spin}(V)$ is a Lie group, and ${\frak spin}(V)$ is the corresponding lie algebra.

Comment: @runway44 In my application, I obtain $\exp( {\mathfrak{so}}(3,1) \oplus \mathfrak{u}(1))$ for the structure group of my manifold. Can I claim to have a representation of ${\rm Spin}^c(3,1)$? Can I use my group in the sense of a $spin^c$ structure  on a pseudo-Riemmanian 4-manifold yielding a spin connection?

Comment: Dunno about your second question, but for your first it depends on what you mean by $\exp({\frak so}(3,1)\oplus{\frak u}(1))$.

Comment: @runway44 Specifically, I mean the exponential of a bivector of Cl(3,1) and a imagnary ib. $\exp (f_{01}\gamma_0\gamma_1+f_{02}\gamma_0\gamma_2+f_{03}\gamma_0\gamma_3+f_{12}\gamma_1\gamma_2+f_{13}\gamma_1\gamma_3+f_{23}\gamma_2\gamma_3 +i b)$

Comment: @Anon21 In terms of spin and spin c structures there are potential topological obstructions to lifting a pseudo-Riemannian structure to a spin/spin c one (to do with the Stiefel-Whitney classes of your bundle). I think if the manifold is 4 dimensional, closed and orientable then it will always work.

Comment: @Callum Is lifting always required?  Since Spin(2) $\cong$ SO(2), can I get the spin connection from reducing from GL(2) to Spin(2), without having to lift?

Comment: @Anon21 well in that case it wouldn't be a lift at all. $\mathrm{SO}(2)\cong \mathrm{Spin}(2)$ is a weird special case in more than that though. It is abelian and not simply connected

Comment: @Callum What about the $Spin(3,1) \cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. Does it need a lift? Or can I reduce GL(4) to SL(2,C) and get the spin connection?

Comment: @Anon21 How are you viewing $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ as a subgroup of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$? You may need to be careful there. I feel that $\mathrm{Spin}(3,1)$ doesn't have a faithful representation on $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}$ as this is generally true in higher dimensions but I'm not sure there isnt some low dimensional oddity. Either way, reduction of a principal bundle also has topological obstructions.

Comment: @Callum I am viewing Spin(3,1) as represented by the square of the exponential of the bivectors of the clifford algebra 3,1: $R=\exp {-\frac{1}{2}B}$. The squaring $R\to R^2$ makes it so that $-R*-R = R*R$, thus realizing a double cover. Finally, R has a corresponding 4x4 matrix representation using Dirac algebra, which is in GL(4,R).

Comment: You have a homomorphism into $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ but it is not injective. Indeed you are finding a copy of $SO(3,1)$ as a subgroup it seems. So we cannot describe the spin structure as a reduction from $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ in this way

Comment: @Callum If $R=\pm \exp (-\frac{1}{2}B)$, I would think I would get a double copy of SO(3,1), no?

Comment: How can $R$ be two different things at once? Functions only give one output. You are finding a double cover not a double copy. The homomorphism you define should be 2-to-1 and its image will be (a single copy of) $SO(3,1)$.

Comment: @Callum I made a mistake previously. What I actually do is I take the exponential map of the bivectors of $CL(\mathbb{R}^{3,1})$, like this: $R=\exp\frac{1}{2}B$. Vectors transforms as : $v'=RvR^{-1}$. This maps directly to spinors. My mistake in my understanding, was that I thought it mapped to rotors and that I had to do something else to get spinors after that. However, since it maps directly to spinors I do not. I am I correct?